# Curing noncoverage with hot-deck imputation?

Tags: survey, calibration, multiple-imputation

Is it advisable to use hot-deck imputation to allow for poststratification in the presence of empty post-strata?

In a survey reweighting exercise, I have population totals for a complete cross-classification of four attributes: country, age, sex, and work status. However, the survey suffers from noncoverage: For a few category combinations, there is no corresponding sample in the survey. This means that simple post-stratification cannot be applied directly.

For the missing category combinations, I could use survey records that are "similar" to the missing ones (hot-deck imputation), and then apply simple post-stratification. I could even repeat this $k$ times and average over the $k$ sets of weights. **Question**: Is this considered "better" or "worse" than collapsing post-strata or using GREG estimation? Why? (Pointers to literature are welcome, too.)

The following questions are related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29132/6432, [Effects of ignoring the sampling strategy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29133/6432)

Comment: If I understand you right, you are going to create the needed amount of cases (respondents) filling the empty cells of the cross-classification. Then, because these newly invented cases are missing on all the rest questions of the survey you plan to imput them from "similar" cases. But what on earth can be the background ("deck") variables on the basis of which to establish similarity, all variables (except country/age/sex/status) being missing for that cases?

Comment: @ttnphns: I would consider two cases similar if they differ in only one attribute (except "work status") and if the age is $\pm 1$ or $\pm 2$ classes away. Do you consider this insufficient?